# SQL: get undirected links in directed graph

Tags: sql, graph

I have a table holding edges in a directed graph:

```
CREATE TABLE edges ( 
    from_here int not null, 
    to_there  int not null
)
```

How can I do a Select on this table disregarding all back links? For example from this table:

```
+------------+----------+--+
| from_there | to_there |  |
+------------+----------+--+
|          1 |        2 |  |
|          2 |        1 |  |
|          3 |        4 |  |
+------------+----------+--+
```

I want to get this result:

```
+------------+----------+--+
| from_there | to_there |  |
+------------+----------+--+
|          1 |        2 |  |
|          3 |        4 |  |
+------------+----------+--+
```

In other words, how can I get for each bidirectional link just the forward link? We cannot assume that a reciprocal edge always exists.

**EDIT** The goal is to get one row per bidirectional link, it does not matter whether it is the forward or backward link

Comment: How do you decide which is the forward link?  In the example above, why return 1-2, instead of 2-1?

Comment: It does not matter which one, I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right

```
select from_there, to_there
from edges x
where not exists (
    select 1 from edges y 
    where x.from_there = y.to_there
      and x.to_there = y.from_there
      and x.to_there < y.to_there
);
```

Comment: Thanks but the numbers do not follow any order, we cannot rely on them being ascending

Comment: You have to choose one of the edges (1,2) or (2,1) somehow. In my suggestion (1,2) is picked. If you change to `x.to_there > y.to_there` you will get (2,1)